# Scroll to next/previous checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am implementing a marker/anchorpoint system in my application. I am getting a bunch of data from server regularly using socket programming.

I made a demo here in fiddle, the thing that I have having difficulty with is that I want to scroll to all checked checkbox the same way that text searches scroll to matches when you hit next or previous. If user clicks the "Next" button it should go to the next checked checkbox. Likewise, if user presses the "Previous" button, it goes previous.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/TnTj9/7/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button id="next">next</button>
    <button id="previous">previous</button>
</div>
<div id="left">
    <div class='cb'>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="realTimeContents" class="left realtimeContend_h"><!-- this gets populated --></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var h = -1;
    setInterval(function () {
        var newHeight = $('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii. is div").height();
        if (h == -1) h = newHeight;
        if (h != newHeight) {
            //    alert(newHeight);
            h = newHeight;
            $("#left").append("<div class='cb'><input type=\"checkbox\" /></div>");
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

I haven't really made any progress in finding/scrolling to the checkboxes, but I think something like this could be used:

```
 scrollTop: $('.match').eq(searchIndex).get(0).offsetTop
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? I created a `checked` array that contains the indexes of the checkboxes that are checked. Then when next or previous are clicked I change the `current` var which keeps track of the current box as well as scrolling to that particular box.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TnTj9/12/)

```
var checked = [];
var current = 0;
$("#left").on("click", "input", function () {
    checked = [];
    var $cbs = $("#left").find("input");
    $("#currRow").text($cbs.index(this));
    $cbs.filter(":checked").each(function () {
        checked.push($cbs.index(this));
    });
});

$("#next").on("click", function () {
    var idx = (checked.indexOf(current) + 1) % checked.length;
    gotoBox(idx);
});

$("#previous").on("click", function () {
    var idx = (checked.indexOf(current) - 1);
    if (idx < 0) idx = checked.length - 1;
    gotoBox(idx);
});

function gotoBox(idx) {
    current = checked[idx];
    $("#currRow").text(current);
    var $box = $("#left").find("input").eq(current);
    var $content = $("#content");
    $content.scrollTop(
    $box.offset().top - $content.offset().top + $content.scrollTop());
}
```

**Note:** I sped up the intervals so this could be tested with larger content more quickly.

Comment: can you please explain  $content.scrollTop(
    $box.offset().top - $content.offset().top + $content.scrollTop());
}

Comment: `$content.scrollTop(value)` sets where the scroll is positioned on the `$content` div. `offset()` gets the position of the element relative to the document with properties including `top`.  `scrollTop()` gets the current scroll position. So we are SETTING the scroll position to the `offset of checkbox to go to` minus the `offset of the actual content div` plus how far the scroll is currently down. As `offset()` is based on the document, we want to subtract how far the `$content` is down from the top of the document so this isn't counted.

Comment: If `$content` is 100px from the top of the document and we are currently scrolled to the top of content and the top checkbox is checked. `$content.scrollTop()` will be `0`, `$content.offset().top` will be `100px`, and `$box.offset().top` will be slightly more than 100, lets say `105px`. So we get 105 - 100 + 0 = 5px. It will scroll down 5px so the box is at the top. If we are scrolling to that same box but we start off scrolled down 1000px. The calculation would be like -905 - 100 + 1000 = 5px. The reason the `$box.offset().top` is -905 is because scrolling content down brings box up past top.

Comment: awesome man thanks for support ..clearly understand